# Checking whether an arbitrary field is valid for user entity

Tags: 8, entities, users

In my module I have a form where I want to give an admin the ability to configure which user field they want to put certain data in. In the context of the admin form, I'd like to verify that the field actually exists.

If I have a given user, I can probably use:

```
$userEntity->hasField('custom_field')
```

What is the correct way to do this when I don't have any specific user entity? After all, fields should be the same for any user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for users you can't configure different bundles like content types for nodes. So fields are the same for any user.

If you don't have an existing user you can create one temporarily:

```
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

$field_exists = User::create()->hasField('custom_field');
```